# Could anyone help me witht the following error message "TclError: Can't find a usable init.tcl"?

Tags: anaconda, tcl, tk-toolkit

I'm trying to run a code that uses tcl/tk and I have tried many options from similar error questions but non of the work, anyone that could help? This is the message:

C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/tcl/tcl8.6/init.tcl: version conflict for package "Tcl": have 8.6.9, need exactly 8.6.6
version conflict for package "Tcl": have 8.6.9, need exactly 8.6.6
while executing
"package require -exact Tcl 8.6.6"
(file "C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/tcl/tcl8.6/init.tcl" line 19)
invoked from within
"source C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/tcl/tcl8.6/init.tcl"
("uplevel" body line 1)
invoked from within
"uplevel #0 [list source $tclfile]"

This probably means that Tcl wasn't installed properly.

Answer (score 1):

That means that the version of the C code in the Tcl library that Anaconda is using is not exactly matched to the version of the accompanying Tcl code; the two are really supposed to be co-deployed as they are designed with intimate knowledge of each other. It looks like the version of the Tcl code is newer than the version of the (shared?) library. That's broken! I don't know why that's a bit inclined to happen with Anaconda; I don't do any support of it at all.

The actual changes between the Tcl files are mostly not very large, as it happens. And the actual current version is 8.6.12 so you're definitely behind either way.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I think that makes a lot of sense. Would you recommend to upgrade Tcl/Tk to solve the problem?